# SQL : multiple INT columns as primary key, or a VARCHAR?

Tags: sql, primary-key

If I have the following table, what is the best practice for creating a primary key?

A combination of these 3 `INT`s will always create a unique identifier, thus my primary key. Should I assign all three columns to a primary key?

```
col1  |  col2  |  col3
1        50       1540
2        50       1540
1        50       1541
1        51       1540
```

Would is be smarter just to create a single column primary key as `CHAR(N)` or `VARCHAR` as seen in the following?

```
50_1540_1
50_1540_2
50_1541_1
51_1540_1
```

I am considering performance issues, as the table could exceed 100 million rows

Answer (score 0):

Which is smarter?  For this particular case, assign all three columns as the primary key.  Here are three reasons:

- Why duplicate the space for the columns?
- You probably want to keep the original columns because they -- presumably -- mean something.
- Foreign key relationships need to reference all three columns, and if you have a new concatenated column, you would need concatenate the values in all referencing tables.

That said, I'm not a fan of composite primary keys.  I would recommend that you declare the three with a `unique` constraint (or index).  Then have an auto-incremented key as the primary key for the table.

Comment: I'm curious about your option regarding using composite primary keys for many-to-many `JOIN` tables? In such cases, would it make sense to use the two foreign keys as a primary key for the `JOIN` table? (Asking for a friend. ;) )

Comment: @daShier . . . I prefer synthetic auto-incremented keys for all tables, including junction/association tables.  However, I appreciate that some database designers do not see the need for them.

Comment: @GordonLinoff When you say declare the 3 with a unique constraint, does that mean the combination of 3 will have to be unique?  And an auto incremented key would just be 1,2,3 etc...?  At that point, what is the point of having a primary key other than a unique identifier? Primary key # 126484 means nothing to me, and I would never query or join tables using it

Comment: @LotsOfQuestions94 . . . The unique constraint would be on the triple, the combination of the three values.  Primary keys are very useful for foreign key relationships and for identifying specific rows (say for updates or deletes).  Incremental keys also provide information on insertion order.